# ESLint getting Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression when using shorthand

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

In React (not really relevant to my question), I have the following:

```
const Curious = true;
useEffect(() => {
  Curious && initSearch();
}, [Curious, initSearch]);
```

I'm getting `"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"` on `Curious && initSearch();`
But that line should be equivalent to writing the following, which doesn't give me the warning:

```
const Curious = true;
useEffect(() => {
  if (Curious) { initSearch() };
}, [Curious, initSearch]);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent, and you shouldn't write the misleading `&&` expression but the proper `if` statement.

Comment: @Bergi if they are equivalent, then why is `&&` misleading?

Comment: Because it's unidiomatic, and not even a lot shorter. A `&&` produces a value, which you don't want here, so you shouldn't use it (it's even worse in [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23183972/1048572)). That's what linter style warnings are all about.